BibTeX setup doesn't recognize citations
I have a very barebones file that I just want to get citations working on:
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\title{...}
\author{...}
\date{\today}

\bibliographystyle{plain}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
test \cite{compcert2016}
\bibliography{project-refs.bib}
\end{document}


And I have do have project-refs.bib set up in the same directory with compcert2016 as a defined paper, but I get the following error message:
I found no \citation commands
I found no \bibdata command
I found no \bibstyle command

I'm not using any of these commands, but I don't think they're necessary. What am I missing here to get a proper bibliography?

you need to run pdflatex then bibtex then pdflatex then pdflatex again. latex itself never reads the bib file

In bibex you don't need to add the file type: \bibliography{project-refs}
